# Changing border color based on method output ionic

Tags: angular, ionic2

I have app with list of cards. Card has left border:

```
 .card-border {
    border-left: 6px solid;
  }
```

I have  method that returns name  of the color specified in colors map at variables,scss. How can I bind my method output to border-color attribute?

I can apply color by using  `ngStyle` but not sure how to bind my custom colors from my method output.

```
 [ngStyle]="{'border-color':  'red'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

If it does return the name of the color you just need to pass it as a string to a variable.

In your .ts file you'll have

```
public myColor: string;

myMethodWhoPickColors(){
  // CODE CODE CODE
  // returned color as return
  this.myColor = return;
};
```

and in your `ngStyle`

```
[ngStyle]="{'border-color':  myColor}"
```

Hope this helps :D